# Angular Auth0 email_verified issue

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I am having a weird issue with Auth0 on my Angular App. After users confirm their email via a link sent to their email accounts, `auth.profile.email_verified` does not point to a "truthy" value consistently, meaning sometimes it is `true` but sometimes it is `false`. It is even stranger that if I `console.log(auth)` and drill into the "profile" key, `email_verified` is always `true`, while that is not the case when I `console.log(auth.profile)`. I looked through the docs but didn't find any answer to that issue.  If I use `auth.getProfile()` I always get `profile.email_verified : true` in the promise but I don't want to depend on that promise to check the value of `email_verified`. `auth.profile.email_verified` will start pointing to a truthy value consistently only after I logout and log back in.

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 Engineer here,

The problem is caused by the following 3 cases:

1. The user logged in with a social provider that verifies the account and makes it visible or with passwordless email provider. The profile will receive `email_verified` as `true`.
2. The user logged in via email/password or a social provider where email is not verified. The profile will receive `email_verified` as `false`.
3. The user went and accepted the application and approved his email. The profile will always return `email_verified` as `true`.

Now in your application, To handle all the cases you'll have to handle this more gracefully and you will have to fetch the profile after the verification is complete.

Comment: We got it to work by saving  `email-verified: true` on "our own" user profile once the email is verified and fetched. We can now read the value from that key instead of fetching multiple times from auth0. Thanks much.